# aws http api increase Payload size

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, http, aws-api-gateway

Is there a way to increase the payload size of the http api in aws gateway? For the same multi-form part request having two files of 1.1 MB and 4 MB, a http api fails to execute. Whereas the rest api works fine.

The response that i get back for the http api is

```
{
    "message": "Request Entity Too Large"
}
```

and the status code is

```
413 Payload Too Large
```

Comment: If your form need to upload some file on server, then you can do it by uploading a file on s3 first using pre-signed URLs, and then posting the reference of the S3 key in the payload.